# How to optimize PostGIS Intersection Query

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, optimization, st-intersects

I've 2 sets of polygons in 2 tables and the sets overlap each other. For each polygon in set A, I get the ID of the polygon in set B that it overlaps the most.

This is the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (a.id)
  a.id as a_id,
  b.id as b_id,
  ST_Area(ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom)) as intersect_area
FROM a, b
ORDER BY a.id, ST_Area(ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom)) DESC
```

It works properly so, what's the problem? It's very slow (it takes several minutes). Table "a" has more than 10,000 rows and table "b" 700 rows. So, how can I improve the perfomance?

I've tried with spatial index but I haven't had better results.

Comment: Your query result should have 10000*700 rows ... because your forget the **where** condition to take in account **only** the features of a and b that really intersect.

Comment: please always add the results of an `EXPLAIN` or `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` run in SQL query questions.

Answer (score 7):

An implicit `CROSS JOIN` (`a, b`) creates an unconditional (no `WHERE`) *cartesian product* of both tables, that is, for **every row** in `a`, join **every row** of table `b` - massing up `10.000 * 700` rows in the result set! The `DISTINCT ON` filter adds overhead in parsing the complete result set for un-indexed duplicates, and the `ORDER BY` is equally not optimized.

It is good practice to express relationships with explicit `JOIN` statements, and use conditional expressions that can actually utilize (spatial) indexes.

Since a full traversal of `a` is the basic idea behind your task, to actually get a **conditionally limited (ordered) result set** per row you want to use the `LATERAL JOIN` mechanics:

```
SELECT a.id,
       i.id,
       i.intersect_area
FROM   a
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT b.id,
         ST_Area(ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom)) AS intersect_area
  FROM   b
  WHERE  ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)
  ORDER BY
         2 DESC
  LIMIT  1
) AS i ON TRUE
;
```

While traversing `a`, the `LATERAL JOIN` passes the current row of `a` into the sub-query, where `ST_Intersects` filters (index driven) for intersecting polygons in `b`, and returns only the one (`LIMIT 1`) with the largest intersection area (`ORDER BY [ST_Area(ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom))]`). Using a `LEFT JOIN` ensures that rows in `a` with no overlapping geometries in `b` will be kept in the result; if that is undesireable, use `CROSS JOIN LATERAL (<sub_query>) AS i` without `ON TRUE`.

**Notes:**

- an index on `b.geom` is mandatory
- the result of `ST_Area` will be in **units of CRS** - which, if applied to a *geographic reference system* with ***degree*** as unit, is useless - either project (`ST_Transform`) to a suitable projection, or use a cast to `GEOGRAPHY`

Comment: For other proposites for example performance can be equal cross to a left join  en this case?